# App not working in API level 15 (configspec for surfaceview not matched)

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I might expect some specific function not working, as the application works fine for API level 23...

However the app I worked on is simply failing completelly, due to an error:

```
12-03 01:04:35.576    1373-1387/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 71
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:853)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1009)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1362)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1216)
```

Looking at the my surfaceview class:

```
class DirectionGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    private final DirectionGLRenderer mRenderer;

    public DirectionGLSurfaceView(Context context){
        super(context);

        // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        mRenderer = new DirectionGLRenderer();
        setEGLConfigChooser(8 , 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find a direct cause?

EDIT: I should mention that I use a virtual device for testing,
"nexus 4, edited to use android api 15" is the offensive one
"nexus 4, edited to use android api 16" actually works. (Yes api is the only difference).

Comment: The config you're trying to choose doesn't exist on this device.  Try another one.

Comment: @GabeSechan but that makes no sense - you're telling me API 15 doesn't have 32-bit colour support?

Comment: That's what the device is telling you GLSurfaceView.BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig is throwing an IllegalArgumentException that no configs match configSpec.  It might be the depth instead, but your device isn't supporting it.  Its also very device specific-  some devices are known not to support that config (I've found mentions of the ZTE Blade for one).  Its not about the API level, its about the physical GPU hardware.

Comment: @GabeSechan ok worth mentioning then that I choose a virtual device "nexus 4, edited to use android api 15"